# How would I change the gedit theme/colour scheme? (20.04 LTS)

Tags: gnome, themes, gedit

At the moment every time I try to run gedit I get the following error:

`** (gedit:42831): WARNING **: 17:39:58.054: Default style scheme 'pop-light' cannot be found, falling back to 'classic' style scheme`

`** (gedit:42831): WARNING **: 17:39:58.058: Loading metadata failed: The specified location is not mounted`

I did previously have the Pop!_OS theme running, but this is the error I started getting when I switched back to default and removed the Pop!_OS theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the gedit preferences. Depending on your Ubuntu version (not mentioned) this will be found in different locations.

Then go to font and colours tab. Select something appropriate for you. You might need to uncheck the system font option.

[image: Font and colours preferences form Ubuntu 20.04]